# Solving a non-linear Schrödinger equation

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, warning-messages

I am trying to use `NDSolve` to solve numerically the well-known Schrödinger-Newton equation for a certain initial value of the wave function.

```
ClearAll[r, t, ψ, ϕ]

σ = 1

sol = NDSolve[{I*D[ψ[r, t], t] == -1/(2)*D[ψ[r, t], {r, 2}] + ψ[r, t]*ϕ[r, t], D[ϕ[r, t], {r, 2}] == σ*ψ[x,t]*ψ[x, t]\[Conjugate], ψ[r, 0] == (2/Pi)^(3/4)*Exp[-r^2], ψ[-100,t] == (2/Pi)^(3/4)*Exp[-100^2], ψ[100, t] == (2/Pi)^(3/4)*Exp[-100^2], ϕ[-100, t] == 0, ϕ[100, t] == 0, ϕ[r, 0] == 0}, ψ, {r, -100, 100}, {t, 0, 1}, Method -> Automatic]
```

Mathematica says 'NDSolve::delpde: Delay partial differential equations are not currently supported by NDSolve'. Do any of you know how to re-express the problem in order to get the solution?

Comment: The code is missing a differential equation for `ϕ[r, t]`, which is why Mathematica provides the warning, "Some of the functions have zero differential order, so the equations will be solved as a system of differential-algebraic equations."  Please provide the equation to `NDSolve` to see if this gives you an answer.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo:

```
D[ϕ[r, t], {r, 2}] == σ*ψ[x,t]*ψ[x, t]\[Conjugate]
```

`x` should be `r` in the above snippet from your code. It is interpreting the equation as a delayed equation because it thinks you are meaning to call `ψ` at the (undetermined) value `x`. Although, my machine still is not powerful enough to produce the solution. Maybe yours is.